# Git pull gives error: file write error (Bad file descriptor)

Tags: git, pull-request, hpc, git-pull

I'm working on an HPC cluster and when trying to git pull a project to the cluster I get the following error:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 99, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (99/99), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (53/53), done.
error: file write error (Bad file descriptor)
fatal: unable to write sha1 file
```

For more information, we are three people working on the same project and have tried running the following command on the cluster.

```
chgrp -R <project name> .
```

But that gives us this error:

```
chgrp: changing group of './__pycache__/G_fine_tune.cpython-38.pyc': Operation not permitted
chgrp: changing group of './job.71224.out': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: To be more clear, do the three of you actually work in the same sandbox? That's a recipe for problems, but one way to make it work it to set default ACLs so that any new files created under the common space get read-write permissions for the group (or by team members). Changing the group after the fact like you're doing might require each team member to fix the files they own in there, which is probably why you got that error. Or else a sys admin might have to do it for you.

Comment: But default ACLs are much more convenient, as those will have a lasting effect on everything you do in that shared directory.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory

Comment: "Operation not permitted" is an error code meaning that you can't do that, not because you don't have permission (that would be "permission denied" instead) but because the underlying file system denies the entire concept of changing the group ID of a file. You typically get this with a file system type that doesn't have "group ownership" as a Thing.